# Rendering CSS background-image

Tags: css, xhtml

I have an image on server folder (C:\resources\image\client-a.jpg). Is it possible to render the background-image in such a way that if client-a.jpg is available, then render it else render client-default.png?

```
    <style type="text/css">
    #divElement {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        margin-top: -200px;
        margin-left: -400px;
        background-image: url(/TestWeb/theme/client-default.png);
        width: 800px;
        height: 400px;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple images provided they are not transpareny like this

```
background-image: url(/image/client-a.jpg),url(/image/client-default.png);
```

So when the first is not available the second will be displayed.

Comment: In future, I may have client-b.jpg, client-c.jpg etc... this might not work for me. I think keeping the image outside of context root is better.

Comment: By context you mean other network location right? you can do this `background-image: url(http://full/client-a/address.jpg),url(http://full/client-b/address.jpg),url(/TestWeb/theme/client-default.png);`

Comment: nope, I meant server location C:\resources\image\client-a.jpg

Comment: `url(C:\resources\image\client-a.jpg)` will pobably work but only on your server.. You have to host your images somewhere or have them on somekinda webserver so the url starts with `http:..` and not `c:..`